# Auto scale axis lattice in R

Tags: r

I have multiple graphs included in one plot and I would like to increase axis density. How I can do this? I know one can assign manualy for example `scales=list(y=list(at=seq(0,1,0.2)), x=list(axs='i', draw=FALSE)), xlim=c(-1,2.5)` but I have large amount of plots plus data vary considerably. So how to set auto.scale so that the axis is more dense?

Sample data and output:

```
 lattice(lattice)
 lattice(gridExtra)
 rdata <- data.frame(y=rnorm(1000,2,2),v1=rnorm(1000,1,1),v2=rnorm(1000,3,3),
                    v3=rnorm(1000,4,4),v4=rnorm(1000,5,5))


 plot1 <- lapply(1:2, function(i) {bwplot(~rdata[,i],rdata)})
 plot2 <- lapply(1:3, function(i) {bwplot(~rdata[,i],rdata)})
 plot3 <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {bwplot(~rdata[,i],rdata)})


 # arrange list of grobs for each plot
 l <- lapply(list(plot1, plot2, plot3), 
        function(i) do.call(arrangeGrob, c(i, list(nrow=1, ncol=4))))

 # plot
 do.call(grid.arrange, l)
```

EDIT: including `scales=list(x=list(at=pretty(rdata[,i])))` won't help either.

Comment: Have you tried asjusting the `tick.number=` parameter? For example `scales = list(x=list(tick.number=10))`. Also, `pretty` has a parameter you pass to request a certain number of breaks. So `scales=list(x=list(at=pretty(rdata[,i], 10)))`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the pretty breaks!Thanks.